# How to avoid my array from being reassigned values as I progress through my loop?

Tags: c#, nested-loops, jagged-arrays

Here is my code below-

```
double[][] geometricReturnsArray = new double[returnsArray.Count][];;
double[] tempGeometricReturns = new double[returnsArray[0].Count];
double return_1 = 0;
double return_2 = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < returnsArray.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < returnsArray[i].Count - 1; j++)
            {
                return_1 = returnsArray[i][j + 1];
                return_2 = returnsArray[i][j];
                tempGeometricReturns[j] = ((return_1 - return_2) / return_2) * 100;
            }
            geometricReturnsArray[i] = tempGeometricReturns;
        }
```

The issue I'm facing in the code is that `tempGeometricReturns` keeps getting reassigned as `i` increases. So in the end, all three arrays of `geometricReturnsArray` have exactly the same values since when `tempGeometricReturns` gets reassigned, so do the previous values in `geometricReturnsArray`.

I tried to use lists as well but then I just get a long list of 267 values whereas I'd prefer three arrays of length 90. What else can I try to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you will end up with multiple references to the same array in  the `geometricReturnsArray`. Arrays are reference types, so assignments only copy the reference, not the entire array.

The fix is to create a new array for each outer loop, for example by copying the existing array when doing the assignment

```
        }
            geometricReturnsArray[i] = tempGeometricReturns.ToArray();
    }
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < returnsArray.Count; i++)
{
    double[] tempGeometricReturns = new double[returnsArray[0].Count];
    for (int j = 0; j < returnsArray[i].Count - 1; j++)
    {
```

Comment: "The fix is to create a new array for each outer loop"  I agree. "for example by copying the existing array when doing the assignment"  That seems strictly worse than just moving `double[] tempGeometricReturns = new double[returnsArray[0].Count];` inside the outer loop, which avoids the unnecessary copy.

Comment: @Ben voigt Agree, picked that option because it was simplest, And because most probably the difference will not be noticable. Still, added your variant for completeness.